# Using neural network trained by weka

Tags: c#, neural-network, weka

I used weka to train a neural network and  I have all the weights and thresholds from weka saved in a file. Now I want to use that data inside my mobile application and I want to do only the forward pass and get the results.

I am using this sigmoid function for it which is the same as used by weka:

```
 if (sum < -45)
  result =0 ;
 else if (sum > 45)
 result = 1;
 else
   result = (double)1 / (1 + Math.Exp(-sum));
```

but I am not getting correct results at all. Am I missing something? or is it even possible to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: could you post the _incorrect_ results and the results expected?

Comment: I got 90% correct results and I guess they are good for my application